# How to Extract value from Parameter Key

Tags: roomle

I know its possible to read a parameter externally from the iFrame of the configurator

```
const frameColour = params.find(({ key }) => key === "frameColour");
```

but is it possible to on the ADD TO CART action to read the value of a Parameter Key (frameColour) and display it in an HTML DIV / Input? The reason for this is I have the parameter key that is the colour of the Shelf Frame I'm building, I want to be able to read the colour and display it to the Screen, then I can store that colour in my external database

Answer (score 1):

After you've created a new configurator using the embedding API you can use this to get notified about parameter updates:

```
configurator.extended.callbacks.onUpdateParameters = (parameters) => {
        // add your logic here
    };
```

`configurator.extended` will give you access to the `RoomleConfigurator` instance (https://docs.roomle.com/web/api/classes/roomleconfigurator.html)